# Babylonian method recursion exception : stackOverFlow

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote code to get a number of square root using in babylonian method.

I ask input number of user, then ask user's guess.

```
public class JanghyupLee_H02 {

private double number;
private double guess;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String input;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    JanghyupLee_H02 AR = new JanghyupLee_H02();

    System.out.println("Type a number : ");
    input = userInput.next();

    if (input.equals("0") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.exit(0);

    } else {

        AR.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(input));

    }

    System.out.println("Type your guess : ");
    input = userInput.next();

    if (input.equals("0") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else {

        AR.setGuess(Double.parseDouble(input));

        double newGuess = AR.getGuess();

        AR.testGuess(newGuess);

    }

}

public double getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(double inputNumber) {
    this.number = inputNumber;
}

public double getGuess() {
    return guess;
}

public void setGuess(double guessNumber) {
    this.guess = guessNumber;
}

public double testGuess(double guess) {
    double guessAcurracy = (getNumber() - (getGuess() * getGuess()));

     //exeption error here
    if ((guessAcurracy == 0) && (guessAcurracy <= 0.000005)) {
        System.out.println(guess);

        return guess;
    } else {

        setGuess((((0.5) * (getGuess() + getNumber() / getGuess()))));
        System.out.println(guess);
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        return testGuess(getGuess());
    }

}
```

}

Basically, guessAcuraccy is subtraction of the first input and two to the

calculated output.(So that the answer getting closer to the input number)

I have an exception error at there,

even if I wrote || instead of &&.(actually, || this doesn't go recursive)

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
> >         at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal$BinaryToASCIIBuffer.dtoa(FloatingDecimal.java:431)
> >         at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal$BinaryToASCIIBuffer.access$100(FloatingDecimal.java:259)

I get those exception error,

please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger?  It's amazing what you can learn by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspicious:

```
double guessAcurracy = (getNumber() - (getGuess() * getGuess()));
```

To compare squares, it should be:

```
double guessAcurracy = (getNumber() * getNumber() - (getGuess() * getGuess()));
```

Or more simply/usually/efficiently:

```
double guessAcurracy = Math.abs(getNumber() - getGuess());
```

This looks suspicious too:

```
if ((guessAcurracy == 0) && (guessAcurracy <= 0.000005)) {
    // stop recursion
```

recursion only stops if `guessAcurracy` is exactly zero, which for the result of a floating point calculation is highly unlikely.

Remove altogether the test for equality with zero.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I tried to change it to ||, but it didn't work

Comment: As Bohemian already said: this can't work. (guessAcurracy == 0) && (guessAcurracy <= 0.000005) is equal to just (guessAcurracy == 0). What you want to do is to use (guessAcurracy <= 0.000005).

Comment: @RobertMcHardy that's exactly what I said in my answer